# How should I understand $\frac {dx(-t)} {d(-t)}$ and relate it to $\frac {dx(t)}{dt}$? This is relevant to ‘Time Reversal Symmetry Theory’.

Tags: derivatives, even-and-odd-functions

Consider a simple classical system that may execute simple harmonic motion, with equation of motion
\begin{equation*}
\frac{ d^2q(t) } { dt^2 }= - \omega^2q(t) \tag{1}
\end{equation*}

I wish to prove, that if $x(t)$ is a solution to **(1)**, then so is $x(-t)$,
i.e. given
\begin{equation*}
\frac{ d^2x(t) } { dt^2 }= - \omega^2x(t) \tag{2}
\end{equation*}

then we must also have

\begin{equation*}
\frac{ d^2x(-t) } { dt^2 }= - \omega^2x(-t) \tag{3}
\end{equation*}

I guess I could use the general solution of **(1)** to show that $x(-t)$ is a solution, if $x(t)$ is, but I would prefer not to think that way.

If we look at trying to get somewhere and do something with **(3)**, we might start by considering it’s LHS.

So, start by considering $  \frac{ d^2x(-t) } { dt^2 }$  hence $ \frac{ dx(-t) } { dt }  $

By the chain rule
\begin{equation*}
\frac{dx(-t)}{dt}= \frac {dx(-t)} {d(-t)}\frac {d(-t)} {d(t)}
  =-\frac {dx(-t)} {d(-t)}
\end{equation*}

My question is: How should I understand  $\frac {dx(-t)} {d(-t)}$ and relate it to $\frac {dx(t)}{dt}$?

I have a suspicion, that the understanding I am looking for, may involve the use of the idea of odd and even functions, but this suspicion may be based upon nonsense.

**Other Information**

I have an understanding of $\frac { dx} { dt }$. If we want a formula for it we may proceed as follows.

There is a function value $x(t)$. Let ‘$t$’ be changed by $\Delta t$, the function value changes to $x(t+\Delta t)$.

The change in the value of the function $\Delta x$, is given by

\begin{equation*}
\Delta x = x(t+\Delta t) - x(t)
\end{equation*}

Form the quotient $\frac{\Delta x } { \Delta t } $
\begin{equation*}
\frac{\Delta x } { \Delta t }= \frac { x(t+\Delta t) - x(t) } { \Delta t}
\end{equation*}

Take the limit of the quotient as $\Delta t \to 0$ and call this limit $\frac { dx} { dt }$.
\begin{equation*}
\frac { dx} { dt } =\lim_{\Delta \to 0}
\frac { x(t+\Delta t) - x(t) } { \Delta t} 
\end{equation*}

Comment: For clarity, write $\tau = -t$. You've used the chain rule to compute $dx/d\tau$ in terms of $dx/dt$; keep going for $d^2 x / d\tau^2 = (d/d\tau) dx/d\tau$.

Comment: You seem to want to change variables to $s=-t$, thus any function $f(t)$ can be viewed as a function of $s$ simply by noting $t = -s$, that is, if $m(t)=-t$ then, as a function of $s$, $f$ is the composition $f\circ m$. You can then compute whatever you need using the chain rule.

Comment: @anomaly I used the chain rule to compute $dx(\tau)/d\tau$ in terms of $dx(\tau)/dt$. I would really like to compute $dx(\tau)/d\tau$ in terms of $dx(t)/dt$.

Comment: Is  $dx(\tau)/d\tau =dx(t)/dt$ ?

Comment: You're trying to show that $y(t) = x(\tau) = x(-t)$ has $y'' = -\omega^2 y$. For a fixed time $t = t_0$ (and thus fixed $\tau = -t_0$), you're going to wind up with something that looks like $x''(-t_0) = -\omega^2 x(-t_0)$. That's fine, because your original differential equation holds for all $t$. But differentiation is local, so you're not going to be able to express $x'(t_0)$ in terms of $x'(-t_0)$. Physically, the velocity of a particle at time $t = 200$ doesn't tell you anything about its velocity at time $t = -200$ (at least, without solving the differential equation governing it).

Comment: The issue here might be a bit of confusion between the differentiating the function $t \to x(-t)$ versus evaluating the derivative of $t \to x(t)$ at $-t$; that is, between $dx(\tau)/d\tau$ and $dx/dt\big\vert_{t= \tau}$. Unfortunately, standard calculus notation is not great for emphasizing this difference.

Comment: @anomaly For odd and even functions, we should be able to express $x'(t_0)$ in terms of $x'(-t_0)$. Then as any function is, I think, a sum of an odd and an even function ....? Just thought I'd mention these things.